# PHP7.1 can not start on centos7.2

Tags: php, bash

I am installing PHP `7.1` on centos `7.2`,
after running `yum install php71`,start `php` via this command:

```
# systemctl start php-fpm
```

error:

```
Failed to start php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

searching `php-fpm` with `find` command:

```
[root@i001 ~]# find / -name php-fpm
/etc/opt/remi/php71/sysconfig/php-fpm  //370Bytes
/opt/remi/php71/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm  //4.21MB
/var/opt/remi/php71/log/php-fpm   //folder
/var/opt/remi/php71/run/php-fpm   //folder
```

The result of `php-v`:

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: `CentOS 7.2` comes with `php-5.x` - where did you install `php71` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have installed PHP 7.1 from my repository.

Please read the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

You have choose to use SCL (for parallel installation), perhaps will be simpler to use standard base packages from remi-php71 repository.

Else, the service name is "php71-php-fpm".